# How do i get a button to call a JS script that removes a text and replaces it with a new text in a grid?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to coding, and i'm working on a school project where we're supposed to make a website using grid.

I have a grid that looks like this "top top top"
                                   "menu bottom pictures"

on the menu side I want to have buttons with different car brands. 
in the "bottom" grid i want to have some information about what the site does which pops up when you open the site. 
When you click on a car brand i want the function to remove the text in "bottom" and replace it with facts about the car brand, and at the same time put a picture or pictures in the "pictures" grid.

as of right now my code looks like this;

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML == "Hello") {
    x.innerHTML = "Masse info om bmw!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="beholder">
  <div class="topp">
    topp
  </div> <!-- topp-->
  <div class="meny">
    <p><button onclick="myFunction()">BMW</button></p>
  </div><!-- meny-->
  <div class="myDIV">Hello</div>
  <div class="bunn">
    bunn
    <p>Her kan du finne ut forskjellig informasjon om forskjellige bilmerker.
    </p>
    <p>Man kan blant annet finne ut hvor de forskjellige bilmerkene blir produsert,</p>
    <p>hvor populære de er, hvilke motorer som brukes samt annen nyttig informasjon.</p>
  </div><!-- bunn-->
  <div class="bilder">
    bilder
  </div><!--bilder-->
</div><!--beholder-->
```

Comment: your code works for me, don't understand what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this code:

```
     <div class="beholder">
 <div class="topp">
        topp
 </div><!-- topp-->


<div class="meny">
<p><button id="bmw">BMW</button></p>  
</div><!-- meny-->

<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

<div class="bunn">
        bunn


        <p>Her kan du finne ut forskjellig informasjon om forskjellige 
 bilmerker.</p>
        <p>Man kan blant annet finne ut hvor de forskjellige bilmerkene 
 blir produsert,</p>
        <p>hvor populære de er, hvilke motorer som brukes samt annen 
 nyttig informasjon.</p>


 </div><!-- bunn-->
 <div class="bilder">
        bilder
 </div><!--bilder-->
 </div><!--beholder-->
  <script>

   window.onload = function() { 
    var btn = document.getElementById("bmw");
    btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
     function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");

        if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
            x.innerHTML = "Masse info om bmw!";
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "3";
            }
    } 
   }

    </script>
```

I made some changes and used event listeners and not the onclick event.

Also I used getElementByID instead of query selector.

Theoretically you could shorten the if conditions with a Ternary conditional operator

```
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML === "Hello" ? "Masse info om bmw!" : "3";
}
```

But the major error should be the not closing script tag.